# Fantasy novel written as first person narrative

Tags: fantasy-genre

I am looking for a fantasy novel written exclusively as a first person narrative, where the world and its creatures, the metaphysics and everything else is gradually revealed to the protagonist.

Has such a novel been written?

If there are none you can think of, do you know one that comes close, i.e. it uses first person narrative in large chunks of the book.

BTW, feel free to re-tag my question. I could not find any really appropriate.

Comment: While I did provide an answer below, I now  feel that this is a list-type question, and perhaps should be closed. The answer at this point can be "Yes, such a novel has been written", and I don't think we should continue listing exemplars.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're not looking for a specific story. If that is correct, I would strongly suggest to remove the *story-identification* tag.

Comment: As mentioned in the [faq], we do not accept questions asking for lists of works. Feel free to ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley).

Comment: The Touchstone Trilogy by Andrea K Host is written like that.

Answer (score 4):

Gene Wolfe's spectacular [Book of the New Sun](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568658079) is a great example of this type of story.

Answer (score 3):

Roger Zelazny's [Chronicles of Amber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Amber) fits the bill, at least in the first novel, Nine Princes in Amber, with the protagonist awakening with a convenient amnesia and slowly discovers what's going on, who he is and what the metaphysics of the world are.

Answer (score 1):

[The Hunger Games trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hunger_Games_trilogy) is written entirely in first person (from the main character Katniss' perspective). The perspective actually struck me as particularly interesting and engaging.

I've actually only finished [The Hunger Games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hunger_Games) and started [Catching Fire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catching_Fire_%282009_novel%29), but I'm pretty darn sure the whole trilogy follows the formula.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look at it. (I'll leave this question open to see if there are any more.)

Comment: @itpastorn Absolutely! I hardly believe THG was entirely original here.